# Unknown SRS in GeoServer for NAD_1983

Tags: geoserver, nad83

I am trying to add a GeoTiff to GeoServer but it is appearing as Unknown in Native SRS. Any idea what could be causing this?

Details for projection are.

```
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_VI_FIPS_0406_Feet", 
  GEOGCS["NAD83", 
  DATUM["North American Datum 1983", 
      SPHEROID["GRS 1980", 6378137.0, 298.257222101, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]], 
      TOWGS84[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
      AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]], 
  PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"], 
  PARAMETER["central_meridian", -116.25], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 32.166666666666664], 
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1", 33.88333333333333], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 21527734.722222216], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 5381933.680555556], 
  PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
  PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2", 32.78333333333333], 
  UNIT["foot_survey_us", 0.30480060960121924], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]
```

Comment: Maybe related: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.geotools2.user/14679

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking this projection up on [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/102646) gives ESRI:102646, while digging around a bit gives [EPSG:2230](https://epsg.io/2230) which GeoServer will recognise:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / California zone 6 (ftUS)",
GEOGCS["NAD83",
    DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",33.88333333333333],
PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",32.78333333333333],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",32.16666666666666],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-116.25],
PARAMETER["false_easting",6561666.667],
PARAMETER["false_northing",1640416.667],
UNIT["US survey foot",0.3048006096012192,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]],
AXIS["X",EAST],
AXIS["Y",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","2230"]]
```

However in both cases the False easting and Northings are different to the ones you have, you are probably best leaving it as unrecognised and let GeoServer reproject it for you. You may also want to check with the data source to find out why they have a broken SRS on their data.

Comment: False Easting/Northing for California zone 6 should be 2000/500km. Seems somebody did the conversion to feet the wrong way round.